# Issue when running a land cover classification based on OBIA

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

I am carrying out a hybrid classification based on OBIA, following the magnificent code that Noel Gorelick and company developed:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fnclinton%2FEE101%3A14%20-%20OBIA

It is just a trial but I would like to see the differences between a hybrid classification considering OBIA and without considering OBIA.

When I run the code, I get the following error: **Output of image computation is too large (8 bands for 3733050 pixels = 113.9 MiB > 80.0 MiB). If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter.**

I am confused, I do not really understand where to specify the 'tileScale' parameter.

The code is the following:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5bb30c868bb6442b60bc688acdf6ae96

```
var region = geometry


/////////////////////////////// SENTINEL 1///////////////////////////////////////////

// Get the VV collection.
var collectionVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.select('VV','VH')

// Create a 3 band stack by selecting from different periods (months)
var im1 = ee.Image(collectionVV.filterDate('2020-05-15', '2020-05-19').mean().divide(100));


print(im1)


function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//////////////////////SENTINEL 2/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-05-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
print(col)

//// PALETTE /////

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

///////////////////////////////ADD BANDS TOGETHER/////////////////////////////////////

// Function to add an NDVI band, treat as above function
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  return image
    .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
    .rename('NDVI'))
    .float();
};


// Function to add an NDVI band, treat as above function
var addSAVI = function(image) {
  return image
    .addBands(image.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': image.select('B8'),
        'red': image.select('B4'),
        'L': 0.2
      })
    .rename('SAVI'))
    .float();
};

var addSENTINEL1 = function(image) {
  return image
    .addBands(im1.select('VV','VH'))
    .float();
};

var dataset = col.map(addSAVI).map(addNDVI).map(addSENTINEL1);

var sentinel = dataset.median().select("B2",'B3','B4','B8', 'NDVI', 'SAVI', 'VV', 'VH').clip(geometry)
var addSENTINEL1 = function(image) {
  return image
    .addBands(im1.select('VV','VH'))
    .float();
};

print(sentinel)

////////////////// SEGMENTATION ///////////////////////////

////Cada seed inicia un objeto nuevo
//Malla de puntos. A partir de estos puntos los clusteres se desarrollaran.
//El numero de seeds ha de ser acorde a los objetos que se quieren encontrar.
//Para encontrar carreteras u objetos mas pequenyos que los crops, se necesitaria una malla con mas seeds

var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(15);

//Map.addLayer(seeds)

// Run SNIC on the regular square grid. (re-name the bands)
var segmentation = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: sentinel, 
  size: 5,
  compactness: 5,
  connectivity: 8,
  neighborhoodSize:256,
  seeds: seeds
}).select(["B2_mean",'B3_mean','B4_mean','B8_mean', 'NDVI_mean', 'SAVI_mean', 'VV_mean', 'VH_mean', 'clusters'], ["B2",'B3','B4','B8', 'NDVI', 'SAVI', 'VV', 'VH', 'clusters'])

print(segmentation)

var clusters = segmentation.select('clusters')

//Map.addLayer(segmentation)
//Map.addLayer(sentinel, rgbVis, 'RGB');

////// REDUCE COMPONENTS in order to get OBJECT VARIABLES //////////////////

//.reduceConnectedComponents (reduce todos los componentes de un cluster a un valor)

// Compute per-cluster stdDev. Indicador de buenos clusters y malos clusters (setdDev alta representa peores clusters)
var stdDev = sentinel.addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.stdDev(), 'clusters', 256)
//Map.addLayer(stdDev, {min:0, max:0.1}, 'StdDev', false)

// Area, Perimeter, Width and Height (cada valor dle pixel representa el area, perimetro y medidas de todo el cluster. 
//todos los pixeles tienen el mismo valor dentro del cluster)
var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.sum(), 'clusters', 256)
//Map.addLayer(area, {min:50000, max: 500000}, 'Cluster Area', false)

var minMax = clusters.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ee.Kernel.square(1));
var perimeterPixels = minMax.select(0).neq(minMax.select(1)).rename('perimeter');
//Map.addLayer(perimeterPixels, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'perimeterPixels');

var perimeter = perimeterPixels.addBands(clusters)
    .reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.sum(), 'clusters', 256);
//Map.addLayer(perimeter, {min: 100, max: 400}, 'Perimeter size', false);

var sizes = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.minMax(), 'clusters', 256)
var width = sizes.select('longitude_max').subtract(sizes.select('longitude_min')).rename('width')
var height = sizes.select('latitude_max').subtract(sizes.select('latitude_min')).rename('height')
//Map.addLayer(width, {min:0, max:0.02}, 'Cluster width', false)
//Map.addLayer(height, {min:0, max:0.02}, 'Cluster height', false)


//////// PUT ALL BANDS TOGETHER (Concatenate) ///////////////

var objectPropertiesImage = ee.Image.cat([
  segmentation,
  stdDev,
  area,
  perimeter,
  width,
  height
]).float();

print(objectPropertiesImage, 'ObjectProperties')


////////////////////// UNSUPERVISED CLASSIFICATION ////////////////////


  // training region is the full image
  var training = objectPropertiesImage.sample({
    region: geometry,
    scale: 10,
    numPixels: 1000
  })

print(  objectPropertiesImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  })
)
  // train cluster on image
  var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(60).train(training)

    // cluster the complete image
  var result_unsupervised = objectPropertiesImage.cluster(clusterer)

////////////////////// SUPERVISED CLASSIFICATION RANDOM FORESTS based on properties image /////////////////////////

////// creating training data and test data ////////////

var TrainingData = urban.merge(water).merge(crops1).merge(bare_crops).merge(roads).randomColumn("random");

print(TrainingData)

var trainingData = TrainingData.filter(ee.Filter.lt("random",0.8))
var testData = TrainingData.filter(ee.Filter.gt("random",0.8))

///// blending training data into the Image /////////////

var TrainingSample = result_unsupervised.sampleRegions(trainingData,["land_class"],10);
var TestSample = result_unsupervised.sampleRegions(testData,["land_class"],10);

var bandNames = result_unsupervised.bandNames()

print(TrainingSample)

var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest(20,0).train(TrainingSample,"land_class",bandNames);

var classification = result_unsupervised.classify(classifier);
print(classification);

Map.addLayer(classification.randomVisualizer())
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the full script? Running what you have here fails because the "urban" image is not defined.

Comment: Yes, the link is the following: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5bb30c868bb6442b60bc688acdf6ae96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is good practice to label you print statements as those are where errors will be thrown. That way you know where to track them down. Something like

```js
print('Some output', eeObject);
```

The errors you are seeing are indicative of a reducer consuming too much memory. The `tileScale` parameter allows you to split up that work into finer chunks on the backend, at the expense of slower execution time.

```
tileScale (Float, default: 1):
A scaling factor used to reduce aggregation tile size; using a larger tileScale
(e.g. 2 or 4) may enable computations that run out of memory with the default.
```

"2 or 4" still yields errors, until you get on up to `tileScale: 16`...

```js
//training region is the full image
var training = objectPropertiesImage.sample({
   region: geometry,
   scale: 10,
   tileScale: 16,
   numPixels: 1000
})

print('count',  
   objectPropertiesImage.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 10,
      tileScale: 16, 
      maxPixels: 1e13
})
)
```

But then the issue goes from memory to timeouts. So I think to get this to work you'll need to export to an asset, which will allow for longer computation times.

```js
Export.image.toAsset(classification);
```

Which will take awhile, but should eventually complete.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/af4413b32e1de7c2d227b7cb5f8731dd?noload=1